# RavenDB not storing document after update values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have a rare problem in RavenDB (using with ASP.NET MVC, C#) and I hope someone can help me out here.

I'll try to explain the context first:

- So basically I have two document stores "Person" (firstname, lastname, projects, ..) and "Project" (name, code, teamMembers, ..).
- A person has one or more projects (e.g. A person made project named X)

The problem:

- For example I link a project to a person
- After this, whenever I try to update some attributes of Project, the project is not getting saved.
- But when this project is not linked to a person, I'm able to edit all fields.

My question:

- Is there any sort of safe option or something that prevents this update. Even better: is it possible to update all documents whenever I change something, regardless changed in Person or Project?

Please if my question is not clear enough I will try to explain in a different way, thanks for any help.

Comment: Showing the code in question would definitely help. Ideally you have already isolated the problem in a short and concise code example that you could share with us so that we have a base for discussion. Right now your question is just some hard to follow block of text without much context.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for the late answer. It was something stupid from me, somewhere I blocked the SaveChanges() with an if.Also I think my approach of saving the document is wrong. I think I just need to save and id instead of the whole document which should make it more consistent and easy to save without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't too much point to add comments then i try to answer your question (that it isn't very clear).

It seems you are trying to implement relational databases logic on a non-realational db (think about this).

I imagine that in the list of Projects you have a property like "ProjectId" that point to the saved document Project/8 (for ex.), this is only a reference that can made easy to load that document, but you must load it to edit.

If you save a document Project/9 and then you add it in the Projects list these are not connected, you need to mantain this manually.

Comment: This makes sense, I've been using relational databases since forever, I recently needed to make a switch and that's why I keep thinking that way. So you're basically saying keeping a list of id's for both project and person will do the job and efficiently? Or how do you recommend it?
Right now I am basically storing the whole document project for example within the document person.. But it's not a good way I suppose as I need to double load and save everything.

Comment: The problem with not saving was solved by the way, it was something with an if blocking the SaveChanges. Silly problem from me.

But my approach of saving doesn't quite feel right and efficient. You guessed right what I'm trying to do, can you provide some more information on how you would deal with this? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It depends on what you need and what you display to users but of course if you want to simulate a many to many relationship, your projects list became a list of ids that point to the related document (ex. Project/8).